# Replace once part of the query in Emacs

Tags: emacs, replace

I have such requirement for search&replace in Emacs:

I have a bunch of

```
'A', 'High'
'B', 'High'
'C', 'High'
'D', 'High'
```

And the list goes on.

I want to replace them to be:

```
A = 'High'
B = 'High'
C = 'High'
D = 'High'
```

Can I query for the pattern, say `'#', 'High'` and replace it with `#= 'High`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move point to beginning of buffer.
<kbd>M-x</kbd> `query-replace-regexp`.
Enter `'\([^']+\)', '\([^']+\)'` as regexp and `\1 = '\2'` as replacement.
Press <kbd>!</kbd> to replace all at once, or keep pressing <kbd>y</kbd>/<kbd>n</kbd>
for each match.